# Cron task doesn't work with SH script

Tags: bash, cron, shell

I have a problem with a cron task, i tried a lot of things but nothing works. I'm on Raspbian and i use `crontab -e` to edit my cron.

I need to run 2 scripts every 1 minute. It works well for the Python script (.py), impossible for the SH.

```
*/1 * * * * /home/root/domoticz/scripts/DOMOTICZ/Home.py
*/1 * * * * /home/pi/Get_temp_bleville.sh
```

I read a lot of forums, I added `#!/bin/sh` or `#!/bin/bash` in the top of the script, I tried a `chmod 777 Get_temp_bleville.sh` for testing purposes.

I tried to change the localtion, the group owner (pi and root)... and these syntaxes :

```
*/1 * * * * /bin/sh /home/pi/Get_temp_bleville.sh
*/1 * * * * /bin/bash /home/pi/Get_temp_bleville.sh
*/1 * * * * bash /home/pi/Get_temp_bleville.sh
*/1 * * * * sh /home/pi/Get_temp_bleville.sh
*/1 * * * * root /home/pi/Get_temp_bleville.sh
```

Nothing to do :(

```
$ ls
-rwxrwxrwx 1 pi   pi    228 déc.  19 21:19 Get_temp_bleville.sh
```

When i start the script directly by `./script` or `bash` or `sh`, it works!

Here's the shell script

The SH script :

```sh
#!/bin/sh
# Get Weather by API
wget -N http://api.wunderground.com/api/3b048a56ce883f41/conditions/q/pws:I76DOLLE2.json

# Get Temperature and parse file + create txt file with the temparature value
cat pws\:I76DOLLE2.json | jq '.current_observation.temp_c' | xargs echo > Temp_bleville.txt
```

What can I do?

Comment: You're running scripts *every minute*? I'd think very carefully about this -- are you sure this is what you want and there's no better way of doing things?

Comment: Yes every minute because it's to refresh a captor value for my home automation system. But i can change for 5 minutes max, it's possible but i don't think that will solve my problem. I have no problem with my Python script, all my SH scripts have the same problem. I don't think that permissions are bad, maybe a path somewhere... impossible to find.

Comment: Does system logs have any error? `/var/logs/system.log`?

Comment: Yes, i enable logs here : /var/log/cron.log

Comment: Does it have any error logs of why it failed to run?

Comment: Try this: `*/1 * * * * /home/pi/Get_temp_bleville.sh >/home/pi/cron.log 2>&1` to see what errors are happening.

Comment: Post the script here. Also, analyze it for errors at http://shellcheck.net

Comment: omg... thanks a lot for this command "/home/pi/cron.log 2>&1"   i read the log and the SH script works but the result is not in the good folder... i'm so stupid, so now it's better with the log system, my first log was not good enough.

Comment: Also see https://askubuntu.com/q/23009/457111

Answer (score -1):

When debugging shell scripts not interactively run, I always start off with the

```
#!/bin/sh # or other shell
```

but immediately follow it with

```
# this redirects output to your log file & sends errors there also
exec > [full path of your own log file] 2>&1 
# This makes the script output each command as it is executed
set +x
```

Given that, either set your paths or put the full path name in front of your commands as in:

```
export PATH=/bin:/usr/bin
```

or

```
/usr/bin/wget -N http://api.wunderground.com/api/3b048a56ce883f41/conditions/q/pws:I76DOLLE2.json
```